# How to open Google Maps to show route using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I read around the Internet but couldn't find a legit answer. I need to open Google Maps when the user clicks a button to show directions. Start and destination must be automatically filled.

How can I achieve this in Swift?

If anyone has a solution, please provide me with a sample code. The start is always going to be the user's current location.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

OK I found the answer myself.

If you want to show directions from the user's current location, leave the field `saddr` blank and in the field `daddr` you can enter the destination coordinates.

This is how I did it

```
if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:
                "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(place.latitude),\(place.longitude)&directionsmode=driving")!)

        } else {
            NSLog("Can't use comgooglemaps://");
        }
    }
```

for any further queries you can refer to this link [Google Map URL Scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme?hl=en)

Comment: sorry, what is your place variable in place.latitude? I have this url "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=2.721966,101.94508010000004&amp;ll=" but I don't know hot to abstract the 2.721966 and 101.94508010000004

Comment: how did you add the buttons? I have managed to show the map and add the marker, but when I click the marker the button does not show up, could you provide your code plz?

Comment: Do you know how to add waypoints (multiple location) to route ?

Comment: I used your code. But I facing issue in my device google map not installed but still not fire else condition.

Comment: @sumesh Your code only shows latitude and longitude but not the address.Can you please share some code for that.

Comment: Shows the current location and destination, does not show the rout until I press the Car or Bike icon on Google Maps. Any Help?

Comment: @AsifHabib Same problem, do you have any update?

Answer (score 47):

**Swift 5 - Code**

```
func openGoogleMap() {
     guard let lat = booking?.booking?.pickup_lat, let latDouble =  Double(lat) else {Toast.show(message: StringMessages.CurrentLocNotRight);return }
     guard let long = booking?.booking?.pickup_long, let longDouble =  Double(long) else {Toast.show(message: StringMessages.CurrentLocNotRight);return }
      if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {  //if phone has an app

          if let url = URL(string: "comgooglemaps-x-callback://?saddr=&daddr=\(latDouble),\(longDouble)&directionsmode=driving") {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:]) 
           }}
      else {
             //Open in browser
            if let urlDestination = URL.init(string: "https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/?saddr=&daddr=\(latDouble),\(longDouble)&directionsmode=driving") {
                               UIApplication.shared.open(urlDestination)
                           }
                }

        }
```

**Don't forget to write this in info.plist**

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
    <string>comgooglemaps-x-callback</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: info.plist data save my time, Thanks

Comment: info.plist saved our lives too

Answer (score 31):

The Answer is already there but in older versions of Swift

**In Swift 3**

```
//Working in Swift new versions.
if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) 
{
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:
    "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(Float(latitude!)),\(Float(longitude!))&directionsmode=driving")! as URL)   
} else 
{
    NSLog("Can't use com.google.maps://");
}
```

Comment: Shows the current location and destination, does not show the rout until I press the Car or Bike icon on Google Maps. Any Help?

Answer (score 28):

For those that the solution for the accepted answer didn't work for them, remember to add `comgooglemaps` to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in the info.plist.

[image: info.plist]

Comment: Shows the current location and destination, does not show the rout until I press the Car or Bike icon on Google Maps. Any Help?

Answer (score 13):

```
@IBAction func NavigationTrackerPressedPressed(_ sender: UIButton){

    if let UrlNavigation = URL.init(string: "comgooglemaps://") {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(UrlNavigation){
            if self.destinationLocation?.longitude != nil && self.destinationLocation?.latitude != nil {

                let lat =      (self.destinationLocation?.latitude)!
                let longi = (self.destinationLocation?.longitude)!

                if let urlDestination = URL.init(string: "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(lat),\(longi)&directionsmode=driving") {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(urlDestination)
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog("Can't use comgooglemaps://");
            self.openTrackerInBrowser()

        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog("Can't use comgooglemaps://");
       self.openTrackerInBrowser()
    }



}
func openTrackerInBrowser(){
    if self.destinationLocation?.longitude != nil && self.destinationLocation?.latitude != nil {

        let lat = (self.destinationLocation?.latitude)!
        let longi = (self.destinationLocation?.longitude)!

        if let urlDestination = URL.init(string: "https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/?saddr=&daddr=\(lat),\(longi)&directionsmode=driving") {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(urlDestination)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**Here is the Swift 3 Update**

First, you need to two items to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in the info.plist.

[image]

Then you can use this function to load address on Google maps.

```
 let primaryContactFullAddress = "No 28/A, Kadalana, Moratuwa, Sri Lanka"

 @IBAction func showLocaionOnMaps(_ sender: Any) {
        let testURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "comgooglemaps-x-callback://")!
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(testURL as URL) {
            if let address = primaryContactFullAddress.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) {
                let directionsRequest: String = "comgooglemaps-x-callback://" + "?daddr=\(address)" + "&x-success=sourceapp://?resume=true&x-source=AirApp"
                let directionsURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: directionsRequest)!
                let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
                if (application.canOpenURL(directionsURL as URL)) {
                    application.open(directionsURL as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                }
            }
        } else {
            NSLog("Can't use comgooglemaps-x-callback:// on this device.")
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for, having the full destination address.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4 Working Code**

```
if let url = URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(location.coordinate.latitude),\(location.coordinate.longitude)&directionsmode=driving") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
    }
```

this code works for me. And ı didn't insert

```
* LSApplicationQueriesSchemes
```

If you use emulator can't see the results. Don't forget work your project on the Phone.

Comment: Will it play voice instructions too ?

Comment: Yes.If your device has Google Map application u can play voice instructions.This coce navigate google maps using browser. When the page is open google show alert automaticly like " open google maps app bla bla"

Answer (score 7):

I want the possibility that the user can open Google Maps via browser (only works when user hasn't the Google Maps App)
Google gives a documentation for that [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme?hl=en#launch_the_google_maps_app_for_ios_from_a_google_maps_desktop_url).
Since iOS 9 you have to set a scheme. This you will find [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#schritt_7_von_der_api_verwendete_url-schemen_angeben).

**For me the google solution doesn't work**. Maybe you are smarter and find a solution (please post!).

Anyway I made a simple web call:

```
let lat = 37.7
let lon = -122.4
if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"https://maps.google.com")!)) 
{
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:
     "https://maps.google.com/?q=@\(lat),\(lon)")!)
}
```

This could be use as a kind of fallback from sumeshs answer.

Answer (score 7):

**1) Method: You can pass the only destination address current address will be automatically fetched by google map application.**

```
let strLat : String = "23.035007"
let strLong : String = "72.529324"

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(strLat),\(strLong)&directionsmode=driving")!)
        }
        else {
            print("Can't use comgooglemaps://");
        }
    }
```

**2) You can pass both start and destination address**

```
let strLat : String = "23.035007"
let strLong : String = "72.529324"

let strLat1 : String = "23.033331"
let strLong2 : String = "72.524510"

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://?saddr=\(strLat),\(strLong)&daddr=\(strLat1),\(strLong2)&directionsmode=driving&zoom=14&views=traffic")!)
        }
        else {
            print("Can't use comgooglemaps://");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
  let lat = self.upcomingListArr[indexPath.item].latitude!
            let long = self.upcomingListArr[indexPath.item].longitude!
            if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")! as URL)) {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:
                    "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(String(describing: lat)),\(String(describing: long))")! as URL)

            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:
                    "https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/?saddr=&daddr=\(String(describing: lat)),\(String(describing: long))")! as URL)
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create small builder for URL, that will redirect you to `GoogleMaps`

```
/*

 add to InfoPlist:

       <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>comgooglemaps</string>
          <string>comgooglemaps-x-callback</string>
        </array>
 */
final public class GoogleMapsURIConstructor {

  public enum NavigationType: String {

    case driving
    case transit
    case walking
  }

  public class func prepareURIFor(latitude lat: Double,
                                  longitude long: Double,
                                  fromLatitude fromLat: Double? = nil,
                                  fromLongitude fromLong: Double? = nil,
                                  navigation navigateBy: NavigationType) -> URL? {
    if let googleMapsRedirect = URL(string: "comgooglemaps://"),
      UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(googleMapsRedirect) {

      if let fromLat = fromLat,
        let fromLong = fromLong {

        let urlDestination = URL(string: "comgooglemaps-x-callback://?saddr=\(fromLat),\(fromLong)?saddr=&daddr=\(lat),\(long)&directionsmode=\(navigateBy.rawValue)")
        return urlDestination

      } else {

        let urlDestination = URL(string: "comgooglemaps-x-callback://?daddr=\(lat),\(long)&directionsmode=\(navigateBy.rawValue)")
        return urlDestination
      }
    } else {
      if let fromLat = fromLat,
        let fromLong = fromLong {

        let urlDestination = URL(string: "https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/?saddr=\(fromLat),\(fromLong)&daddr=\(lat),\(long)&directionsmode=\(navigateBy.rawValue)")
        return urlDestination

      } else {

        let urlDestination = URL(string: "https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/?saddr=&daddr=\(lat),\(long)&directionsmode=\(navigateBy.rawValue)")
        return urlDestination
      }
    }
  }
}
```

usage:

```
  let uri = GoogleMapsURIConstructor.prepareURIFor(latitude: lat,
                                                   longitude: long,
                                                   fromLatitude: userLatitude,
                                                   fromLongitude: userLongitude,
                                                   navigation: .driving)
   UIApplication.shared.open(uri, options: [: ], completionHandler: nil)
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Hi gbk, It shows lat and long on the source and destination in app. This is not good user experience. How can we show real address of those lat long?

Answer (score 3):

If google map app not installed, open with apple map version.

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import UIKit
import MapKit

struct GoogleMapApp {
    func openWithDirection(cordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, locationName: String) {
        let hasGoogleMapApp = UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://")!)

        if hasGoogleMapApp {
            let urlString = "comgooglemaps-x-callback://?saddr=&daddr=\(cordinate.latitude),\(cordinate.longitude)&directionsmode=driving"
            if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
            }
        } else {
            // If google map not installed, open with Apple Map App
            let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: cordinate, addressDictionary: nil))
            mapItem.name = locationName
            mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First off all, thank you guys for your answers beyond. But when I'm working around, I didn't find the working answer for me. And as result I've made working code with two cases: when user has the google maps app and if not.
Here is my version of code. Xcode 10, Swift 4.2. Hope it will help.

**Step 1:** Find your info.plist and Open As -> Source Code

[image: First you should find your info.plist and open it as Source Code.]

**Step 2:** Add these lines between `<dict>` and `</dict>`

[image]

**Step 3:** In your action add this code. Don't forget to set your latitude and longitude.

```
        let latitude = 44.987781
        let longitude = 88.987781
        let appDomen: String = "comgooglemaps://"
        let browserDomen: String = "https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/"
        let directionBody: String = "?saddr=&daddr=\(latitude),\(longitude)&directionsmode=driving"

        // Make route with google maps application
        if let appUrl = URL(string: appDomen), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appUrl) {
            guard let appFullPathUrl = URL(string: appDomen + directionBody) else { return }
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(appFullPathUrl)

        // If user don't have an application make route in browser
        } else if let browserUrl = URL(string: browserDomen), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(browserUrl) {
            guard let browserFullPathUrl = URL(string: browserDomen + directionBody) else { return }
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(browserFullPathUrl)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

// I hope it will work perfactly.

```
let googleURL = NSURL(string: "comgooglemaps://?q=")

if(UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(googleURL! as URL)) {
     UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://?saddr=\(DEVICE_LAT),\(DEVICE_LONG)&daddr=\(addressLat),\(addressLng)&directionsmode=driving")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

//Also set permission from info.plist according to attached image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLVT4.png)

Answer (score 1):

We can use this method to open google maps. If google maps is not installed it will redirect to browser.

```
    func redirectToGoogleMap(coordinates : String) {

       if let url = URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(coordinates)&directionsmode=driving"),
           UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
           print("comgoogle maps worked")
           if #available(iOS 10, *) {
               UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)
           } else {
               UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
           }
       } else{
        if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/?saddr=&daddr=\(coordinates)&directionsmode=driving"),
            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
             print("google com maps worked")
            if #available(iOS 10, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        }else{

           kSweetAlert.showAlert(CommonMethods.setLangText("oops"), subTitle: "Oops! Could not open google maps", style: AlertStyle.error)
        }
       }
   }`
```

Answer (score 1):

SWIFT 5.1 (WORKED FOR ME)

```
// Destination Address (Lat/Long)
let place = business?.businessAddresse
// Google URL
let stringURL = "comgooglemaps://"
// Checking Nil
if !(place?.latitude == nil) || !(place?.longitude == nil) {
  if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: stringURL)!) {
    // If have Google Map App Installed
    if let url = URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(place?.latitude ?? 0.0),\(place?.longitude ?? 0.0)&directionsmode=driving") {
      UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
  } else {
    // If have no Google Map App (Run Browser Instead)
    if let destinationURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/?saddr=&daddr=\(place?.latitude ?? 0.0),\(place?.longitude ?? 0.0)&directionsmode=driving") {
      UIApplication.shared.open(destinationURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
  }
} else {
  // Show Alert When No Location Found
  self.delegate?.noDirectionError(title: "Error", message: "There's no direction available for this restaurant")
}
```

**Note:** This code only work on iOS Version 11 or Later, I hope this helps you guys too, cheer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple solution to choose navigation application between apple and google map(if installed, Otherwise system will navigate to default apple map).

Add this OpenMaps class in your project.

```
class OpenMaps {
        
        // Presenting Action Sheet with Map Options Like Google And Apple Maps.
        /// - Parameter coordinate: coordinate of destination
        static func presentActionSheetwithMapOption(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
            let latitude = coordinate.latitude
            let longitude = coordinate.longitude
            
            // Google MAP URL
            let googleURL = "comgooglemaps://?daddr=\(latitude),\(longitude)&directionsmode=driving"
            let googleItem = ("Google Maps", URL(string:googleURL)!)
            
            // Apple MAP URL
            let appleURL = "maps://?daddr=\(latitude),\(longitude)"
            
            var installedNavigationApps = [("Apple Maps", URL(string:appleURL)!)]
            
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(googleItem.1) {
                installedNavigationApps.append(googleItem)
            }
            
            if installedNavigationApps.count == 1 {
                if let app = installedNavigationApps.first {
                    self.openMap(app: app)
                }
                return
            }
            
            // If there are google map install in the device then System will ask choose map application between apple and google map.
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil,
                                          message: "Choose application",
                                          preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            
            for app in installedNavigationApps {
                let button = UIAlertAction(title: app.0,
                                           style: .default, handler: { _ in
                    self.openMap(app: app)
                })
                alert.addAction(button)
            }
            
            let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(cancel)
            
            guard let vc = AlertViewManager.shared.getTopViewController() else {
                debugPrint("Unable To open the action sheet for maps. Function: \(#function), Line: \(#line)")
                return
            }
            vc.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
        
        // Open Selected Map
        /// - Parameter app: Selected Map Application Details
        private static func openMap(app: (String, URL)) {
            guard UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(app.1) else {
                debugPrint("Unable to open the map.")
                return
            }
            UIApplication.shared.open(app.1, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 30.7333,
                                          longitude: 76.7794)
    OpenMaps.presentActionSheetwithMapOption(coordinate: coordinate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Swift 5 and XCode 13, I was able to use Google's [Universal cross-platform syntax](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started) to open Google Maps app in directions mode.

The link will open the google maps app if it is installed on the phone. If maps is not installed it will open the url in the browser.

```
let url = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=\(coords.latitude)%2C\(coords.longitude)"
guard let googleUrl = URL.init(string: url) else {
    // handle error
    return
}
UIApplication.shared.open(googleUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 4:**

```
 if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")! as URL)) {
       UIApplication.shared.open((NSURL(string:
            "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(trashDictionarySorted[indexPath.section][0])&directionsmode=driving")! as URL), options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

        } else {
            NSLog("Can't use comgooglemaps://");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is already there but in older versions of Swift, And this code can open Google Map in browser if your iPhone did't install Google Map Application.

**In Swift 4**

```
import MapKit

func openGoogleDirectionMap(_ destinationLat: String, _ destinationLng: String) {

    let LocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    if let myLat = LocationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude, let myLng = LocationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude {

        if let tempURL = URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(destinationLat),\(destinationLng)&directionsmode=driving") {

            UIApplication.shared.open(tempURL, options: [:], completionHandler: { (isSuccess) in

                if !isSuccess {

                    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "https://www.google.co.th/maps/dir///")!) {

                        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.google.co.th/maps/dir/\(myLat),\(myLng)/\(destinationLat),\(destinationLng)/")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

                    } else {

                         print("Can't open URL.")

                    }

                }

            })

        } else {

            print("Can't open GoogleMap Application.")

        }

    } else {

        print("Prease allow permission.")

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func openTrackerInBrowser(lat: String, long: String, dlat: String, dlong: String){

    if let urlDestination = URL.init(string: "https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/?saddr=\(lat),\(long)&daddr=\(dlat),\(dlong)&directionsmode=driving") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(urlDestination, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a answer for Swift 4**

First add two items to **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** in the info.plist.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
        <array>
        <string>comgooglemaps</string>
        <string>comgooglemaps-x-callback</string>
        </array>
```

Then you can use the below code to open Google maps and show directions.

```
if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")! as URL)) {
  UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://?saddr=\(sLat),\(sLng)&daddr=\(self.venueLat!),\(self.venueLng!)&directionsmode=driving")! as URL)
  
} else {
  //            Open in browser
  let urlString = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=\(sLat),\(sLng)&destination=\(self.venueLat!),\(self.venueLng!)&travelmode=driving"
  if let urlDestination = URL.init(string: urlString) {
      UIApplication.shared.open(urlDestination)
  }
}
```

here,

- sLat - Starting position latitude
- sLang - Starting position longitude
- venueLat - Destination latitude
- venueLng - Destination logitude

for more references - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme