# How to send a location from my app to other apps in swift?

Tags: swift, location, mapkit

[image]I have a location in my app. I want to make a button that sends this location to other apps like google maps or waze. How can I do that?

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42971577/5447966

Comment: That's not what I want. I want something like the photo I added.

Answer (score 1):

Create a ActionSheet like you have added in image.

And for all the applications in the list like GoogleMaps,Maps,Waze
do the following on click..

```
BOOL canHandle = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps:"]];

if (canHandle) {
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:
            "comgooglemaps://?center=\(self.location.coordinate.latitude),\(self.location.coordinate.longitude)&zoom=14&views=traffic&q=\(self.location.coordinate.latitude),\(self.location.coordinate.longitude)")!
} else {

 //show alert to install googlemaps

}
```