# Swift: Show a list of apps installed on my phone using maps and draw a route on them

Tags: ios, location, maps, share

Is there a way to list all of the apps installed on my device that are using maps and that are able to draw routes from given source to destination location.

I have a requirement where my app allows user to show his route on other navigating apps. I have tried using UIActivityController, but it does not help in this case.

I need to confirm if its possible or not. If its not possible, then require some reference for it.

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671172/how-to-send-a-location-from-my-app-to-other-apps-in-swift), it seems that there is some way to do this.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated

Comment: Hi, do you found how to do this?

Comment: With this Link Get a list of the installed apps on a device. 

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/list_the_installed_apps